# Does "Sneak" increase more quickly with more people involved?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Will sneak experience increase more quickly if 2 people can discover me instead of just one? If so, how much more quickly? And again, if so, is there a limit, for example, will having 20 people be able to discover me increase it even more quickly than 2 people?

Comment: The easiest way to train sneak is at the very beginning of the game, if you went to the keep with Ralof, then as he tells the bear is there, just go into sneak mode, and hit him with a weapon which does least damage for more durability, and do that for about 20-30 minutes and your sneak should be quite close to 100 depending on the race you chose. Hope this helps =)!

Answer (score 2):

Not really answer to your question, but [still](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Sneak_%28Skyrim%29):

> Quickest way to level up sneak. Go to any tavern and find the barman
>   or barmaid. Crouch into a sneak. Find a corner behind the barman and
>   walk backwards while still crouched. Continue walking backwards as the
>   sneak progress bar climbs progressively higher. You can even leave a
>   rubber band on your controllers thumbstick to keep the progress
>   climbing while you step away for an hour. 1 hour of this should
>   increase your sneak at least 30-40 levels minimum. The taverns and
>   inns are the best place to do this as there's always at least 2-3
>   people within distance of you and if you stand behind the barman most
>   will not have line of sight making it next to impossible to fail the
>   skill check.

So the more people are in the area you are practicing sneaking-the more chances you have to really practice it.

Comment: It's been confirmed that moving is not required to train sneaking. Does moving while sneaking increase the speed of training?

Comment: @Arkive Really? I tried not moving while training mine and it seemed to be taking forever. I thought it wasn't even moving at all. When I was moving it was going lightning fast.

Comment: @MrSmooth Yes I've had sneak increase while I was standing still, though I haven't noticed if it was quicker when moving.

Comment: I've had Sneak increase while stationary, but only when enemies were actively searching for me. It's possible that moving _may_ be necessary in the tavern scenario because everyone there is friendly and won't be searching.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is no, the amount of people looking for you has no effect on speed of learning.

However the fastest way to level up sneak is by doing sneak attacks:

Video tutorial here:

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to trek out to the thief stone outside of Riverwood first and get that on you.  20% increase to the speed of 'stealth skills'
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Standing_Stone